# How to set WSGIPassAuthorization when serving Django via runmodwsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using mod_wsgi express to host a Django site. I create the server config by running `./manage.py runmodwsgi` and passing some options like `--setup-only`.

I would like to use HTTP basic auth (using the browser's built-in prompt). I can't find out how to have the auto-generated apache config set this directive:

`WSGIPassAuthorization On`

Is there a way to do this with mod_wsgi express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `mod_wsgi-express` the `WSGIPassAuthorization` directive is always set to `On`, it shouldn't need to be enabled.